# Check if next element has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

html structure:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span"></div>
   <div class="span"></div>
   <div class="navMenu">
       <ul>
           <li><a href=#">Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href=#">Link 1</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I am adding a "new" div just after the above html:

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span"></div>
      <div class="span"></div>
      <div class="navMenu">
        <ul>
           <li><a href=#">Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href=#">Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="new"></div>

$(".navMore li a").each(function() {
   $(this).on("click", function() {
            $('<div class="new"></div>').insertAfter($(this).closest('.row'));
            $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
   });
});
```

Finally I need to check if a div with class `.new` exists RIGHT AFTER the div containing the menu, and if so add a `.span` div in it, and if a div with class `.new` doesn't exist, then create it and then insert a div with class `.span` in it:

```
$(".navMore li a").each(function() {
   $(this).on("click", function() {
      if($(this).next().hasClass("new")){
          $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
      }
      else {
            $('<div class="new"></div>').insertAfter($(this).closest('.row'));
            $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
      }
   });
});
```

It is IMPORTANT that the new div with class `.new` is a div with such a class right next the div container the menu. The reason why is because I will many menus with many different `.row` divs, so I wanted to target the correct one.

The above final code doesn't work tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the each loop - also you notice how `.new` and `.row` are siblings?

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var $row = $el.closest('.row'); // <-- get to row first
  if($row.next('.new').length){ // check next element
      $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
  }
  else {
        $('<div class="new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
        $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
  }
});
```

You also have your classes mixed up.. So you need to make sure they match

```
<div class="navMenu"> <!-- <-- here -->
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and

```
$(".navMore li a") // <-- here
```

Comment: but this assume we already have a div with class .new ? We need to create one first

Comment: isn't that what the else is for? if the next element doesn't have class new.. create one?

Comment: ops sorry.. :) let try it out

Comment: Can we add a loop which we can say that if we added 3 .span div, then we insert a another .new div?

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop is unnecessary. You can just bind a click event to all the items in a selector directly rather than looping through a set and binding them individually.

I would bind the click event to the `.row` divs since the click event will bubble up ... this will make your selectors very easy to test if the next sibling has a `.new` class.

```
$('.row').click(function() {
   var newDiv = $(this).next();
   if(newDiv.hasClass('new')){
      $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo(newDiv);
  }
  else {
        newDiv = $('<div class="new"></div>');
        newDiv.insertAfter($(this));
        $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo(newDiv);
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

The reason why I chose to bind to the .row is because part of the DOM rules about how events propagate up to their parents says that if someone clicks an Anchor tag  then it will send the event up the parents in the DOM. So this means that if we are listening for a click on a parent of an  tag, it will appear as if the click came from that said parent (in this case, a `.row` div).

Comment: why are we clicking on row? should it not be .row ul li a ?

Comment: The reason why I chose to bind to the .row is because part of the DOM rules about how events propogate up to their parents says that if someone clicks an Anchor tag `<a>` then it will send the event up the parents in the DOM. So this means that if we are listening for a click on a parent of an `<a>` tag, it will appear as if the click came from that said parent.

Comment: If you go the other route, tyring to bind to the anchor tag itself (which is completely valid), then you selectors for traversing back up through the dom to the parent div `.row` to check its next sibling becomes a little more messy (IMO). This simplifies the logic a bit. But both approaches are valid.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".navMenu ul li a").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.row').next('.new').length) {
        $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
    } else {
        $('<div class="new"><div class="span">This is a span.</div></div>').insertAfter($(this).closest('.row'));
    }
});
```